# How to SUM query 3 tables?

Tags: mysql

```
A table
--------------------
id bId        txnVolume
1  1(b table) 10.00
2  1          5.00
3  2          7.00
4  3          2.00

B table
--------------------
id cId
1  1(C table)
2  2
3  3

C table
--------------------
id cusId prodId
1  1     1
2  1     2
3  1     1
4  1     2
```

I want to get the sum of txnVolume on table A if C table is custId 1 and prodId 1? Thanks for the help guys! Cheers!

Comment: I can easily write this query for you, but please show us your attempt.  How do you "link" tables together in mysql queries?

Comment: consider: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select sum(coalesce(txnVolume,0))
FROM A INNER JOIN B on A.BID = B.Bid
INNER JOIN C on C.ID = B.CID
WHERE C.CustID = 1 and C.ProdID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
select sum(txnVolume) from A
   join B on A.bID = B.id
   join C on C.cID = C.id
  where prodID = 1 and custID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In sql you need to join the tables.  When tables are joined they create one big table.  You can then add where clauses to the columns.

```
SELECT sum(txnVolume)
FROM A
JOIN B on A.bId = B.id
JOIN C on B.cID = c.id
where c.custid = 1 and c.prodid = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(a.txnVolume)
FROM c 
  LEFT JOIN b 
    ON c.id=b.cId 
  LEFT JOIN a 
    ON b.id=a.bId 
WHERE c.cusId=1 AND c.prodId=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  SUM(a.txnVolume) totals
FROM    tableA a
        INNER JOIN tablB b
            ON a.bid = b.id
        INNER JOIN tableC c
            ON b.cid = c.ID
WHERE   c.custID = 1 AND c.prodID = 1
```